# Tools to create interactive system diagrams?

Tags: modeling, diagrams

I am looking for a tool that would not only allow me to create a system diagram but also allow me to give it some "brains".

For instance, lets say I have 2 main parts of a system depicted by 2 blocks.  I want to simulate what would happen if one of the parts went out so I right click on one of the boxes and select terminate.  The box then turns red, the connection to the other box turns red, and then the final box turns red as well. This indicates that the whole system is down.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what are you looking for, but maybe using code generation from models and/or executable UML tools could help you achieve what are you aiming for. For the particular example you mention, some sort of dependency analysis would suffice, e.g. there are some OSGi tools which can do that AFAIK.